# How data is moving across filters through pins in OBS-Studio virtual camera on windows?

Tags: c++, com, directshow, obs-studio, virtual-webcam

I liked [OBS-Studio](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio)'s virtual camera feature.

I tried to understand its working but could not understand properly. I only understood that it is built using [DirectShow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/directshow). Project contains
[`OutputFilter`](https://github.com/obsproject/libdshowcapture/blob/master/source/output-filter.hpp), [`OutputPin`](https://github.com/obsproject/libdshowcapture/blob/master/source/output-filter.hpp), [`CaptureFilter`](https://github.com/obsproject/libdshowcapture/blob/master/source/capture-filter.hpp) and [`CapturePin`](https://github.com/obsproject/libdshowcapture/blob/master/source/capture-filter.hpp)

```
class OutputFilter : public IBaseFilter {
    // ...
    friend class OutputPin;
    IFilterGraph *graph;
    ComPtr<OutputPin> pin;
    // ...
}

class OutputPin : public IPin, public IAMStreamConfig, public IKsPropertySet {
    // ...
    friend class OutputFilter;
    // ...
}

class CaptureFilter : public IBaseFilter {
    // ...
    friend class CapturePin;
    ComPtr<IFilterGraph> graph;
    ComPtr<CapturePin> pin;
    // ...
}

class CapturePin : public IPin, public IMemInputPin {
    // ...
    CaptureFilter *filter;
    // ...
}
```

How data is moving across these filters and pins when we are enabling virtual camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are using a [shared memory server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/creating-named-shared-memory). Basically, they have a rendering filter that copies the incoming bitmaps into the shared memory. And then they have a capture filter that reads the bitmaps from the shared memory. You can see some of their code here: [win-dshow](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/tree/master/plugins/win-dshow)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is `OutputFilter` mentioned in my question working as rendering filter which you mentioned in your answer? 
Is `CaptureFilter` mentioned in my question same as capture filter mentioned in your answer?

Comment: Use the DirectShow baseclasses: You need a rendering filter based on CBaseRenderer with an input pin based on CRendererInputPin that copies the bitmaps into the shared memory. And then you need a capture filter that's based on CSource with an output pin based on CSourceStream thar reads the bitmaps from the shared memory.

Comment: P.S. The CSourceStream pin has to implement the IKsPropertySet and IAMStreamConfig interfaces.